# Bootstrap is recognized but doesn't function

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm writing my first Bootstrap application and the classes in the tags aren't working.   It works just like unstyled CSS even though I check in javascript that Bootstrap is enabled.

```
<div class="container-fluid">  

<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-12 header">
        <img src="/img/spaceportLogo.png" alt="Spaceport Logo">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-12 hometext">
        <h1>REAL. SPACE.</h1>
        <p>With space available for researching, building and testing a wide range of commercial space applications, the Houston Spaceport offers unparalleled access to the tools, facilities and infrastructure you need.  Click here to learn how you can become a part of the world's first truly urban spaceport.</p>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Here is the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jpking72/026v8eap/1/)

Comment: seems like you've checked for the bootstrap js file, but what about the bootstrap css file?  you're looking for bootstrap.css or bootstrap.min.css

Comment: I just added bootstrap.css same issue

Comment: If I take your fiddle, remove the one resource you added, and then add two resources: one each with the full URL for the CSS and JS (I used ones from  https://www.bootstrapcdn.com/) and then your example came up formatted and seems to work.

Comment: David, if you want the credit, add your answer.   I used the CDN and it worked, my local Bootstrap files must not be right.